# internal server error while calling an api through retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, django, python-3.x, retrofit2

here the 'get' request(student_list) works perfectly fine but when i do the 'post' request(punch) it doen't work but it works through postman

this is my api interface

```
    public interface AuthApi {


    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("students/")
    Call<Person> punch(
            @Field("name") String code,
            @Field("mobile") String mobile,
            @Field("time") String time,
            @Field("late") String late
            );
    @GET("students/")
    Call<List<Person>> studentlist();
}
```

this is my api call

View.OnClickListener submitListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (name.getText().toString().equals("")
            || mobile.getText().toString().equals("")
            || mobile.getText().toString().length() != 10) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "please enter correct credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {


        date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        String time = localDateFormat.format(date);

        String late="";

        if (date.getHours() == 10 && date.getMinutes() > 29 && date.getSeconds() > 0) {

            late=("late by: "
                    + new Integer(date.getMinutes() - 30).toString() + "mins "
                    + new Integer(date.getSeconds()) + "secs");

        } else if (date.getHours() > 10) {
            late= ("late by: "
                    + new Integer(date.getHours() - 10) + "hrs "
                    + new Integer(date.getMinutes()).toString() + "mins "
                    + new Integer(date.getSeconds()) + "secs");
        } else {

            late="in time";
        }

        mApi = new RetrofitHelper<AuthApi>().getApi(AuthApi.class);
        punchCall=mApi.punch(name.getText().toString(),mobile.getText().toString(),time,late);

        punchCall.enqueue(new Callback<Person>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Person> call, Response<Person> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Person> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

};

this is my logcat

```
    06-24 23:51:20.079 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: --> POST http://192.168.0.118:8000/students/ http/1.1
06-24 23:51:20.079 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
06-24 23:51:20.080 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 105
06-24 23:51:20.080 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: name=ket&mobile=8142142827&time=2017%2F06%2F24%2023%3A51%3A20&late=late%20by%3A%2013hrs%2051mins%2020secs
06-24 23:51:20.081 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: --> END POST (105-byte body)
06-24 23:51:20.332 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: <-- 500 Internal Server Error http://192.168.0.118:8000/students/ (250ms)
06-24 23:51:20.333 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: Date: Sat, 24 Jun 2017 18:21:20 GMT
06-24 23:51:20.334 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.5.2
06-24 23:51:20.334 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: Vary: Cookie
06-24 23:51:20.334 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html
06-24 23:51:20.334 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 72215
06-24 23:51:20.334 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
06-24 23:51:20.392 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: <!DOCTYPE html>
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: <html lang="en">
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: <head>
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   <title>TypeError at /students/</title>
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   <style type="text/css">
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     body * { padding:10px 20px; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     body * * { padding:0; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     body { font:small sans-serif; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     h1 { font-weight:normal; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     h2 { margin-bottom:.8em; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     h2 span { font-size:80%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     h3 { margin:1em 0 .5em 0; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     h4 { margin:0 0 .5em 0; font-weight: normal; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     code, pre { font-size: 100%; white-space: pre-wrap; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     table { border:1px solid #ccc; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; background:white; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     tbody td, tbody th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     thead th {
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       padding:1px 6px 1px 3px; background:#fefefe; text-align:left;
06-24 23:51:20.393 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; border:1px solid #ddd;
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     tbody th { width:12em; text-align:right; color:#666; padding-right:.5em; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     table.vars { margin:5px 0 2px 40px; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     table.vars td, table.req td { font-family:monospace; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     table td.code { width:100%; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     table td.code pre { overflow:hidden; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     table.source th { color:#666; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     table.source td { font-family:monospace; white-space:pre; border-bottom:1px solid #eee; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     ul.traceback { list-style-type:none; color: #222; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     ul.traceback li.frame { padding-bottom:1em; color:#666; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     ul.traceback li.user { background-color:#e0e0e0; color:#000 }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     div.context { padding:10px 0; overflow:hidden; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     div.context ol { padding-left:30px; margin:0 10px; list-style-position: inside; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     div.context ol li { font-family:monospace; white-space:pre; color:#777; cursor:pointer; padding-left: 2px; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     div.context ol li pre { display:inline; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     div.context ol.context-line li { color:#505050; background-color:#dfdfdf; padding: 3px 2px; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     div.context ol.context-line li span { position:absolute; right:32px; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     .user div.context ol.context-line li { background-color:#bbb; color:#000; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     .user div.context ol li { color:#666; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     div.commands { margin-left: 40px; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     div.commands a { color:#555; text-decoration:none; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     .user div.commands a { color: black; }
06-24 23:51:20.394 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #summary { background: #ffc; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #summary h2 { font-weight: normal; color: #666; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #explanation { background:#eee; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #template, #template-not-exist { background:#f6f6f6; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #template-not-exist ul { margin: 0 0 10px 20px; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #template-not-exist .postmortem-section { margin-bottom: 3px; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #unicode-hint { background:#eee; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #traceback { background:#eee; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #requestinfo { background:#f6f6f6; padding-left:120px; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #summary table { border:none; background:transparent; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #requestinfo h2, #requestinfo h3 { position:relative; margin-left:-100px; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     #requestinfo h3 { margin-bottom:-1em; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     .error { background: #ffc; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     .specific { color:#cc3300; font-weight:bold; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     h2 span.commands { font-size:.7em;}
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     span.commands a:link {color:#5E5694;}
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     pre.exception_value { font-family: sans-serif; color: #666; font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px 0 10px 0; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     .append-bottom { margin-bottom: 10px; }
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   </style>
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   <script type="text/javascript">
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   //<!--
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     function getElementsByClassName(oElm, strTagName, strClassName){
06-24 23:51:20.395 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         // Written by Jonathan Snook, http://www.snook.ca/jon; Add-ons by Robert Nyman, http://www.robertnyman.com
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         var arrElements = (strTagName == "*" && document.all)? document.all :
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         oElm.getElementsByTagName(strTagName);
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         var arrReturnElements = new Array();
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         strClassName = strClassName.replace(/\-/g, "\\-");
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         var oRegExp = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + strClassName + "(\\s|$)");
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         var oElement;
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         for(var i=0; i<arrElements.length; i++){
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:             oElement = arrElements[i];
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:             if(oRegExp.test(oElement.className)){
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:                 arrReturnElements.push(oElement);
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:             }
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         }
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         return (arrReturnElements)
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     }
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     function hideAll(elems) {
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       for (var e = 0; e < elems.length; e++) {
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         elems[e].style.display = 'none';
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       }
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     }
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     window.onload = function() {
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       hideAll(getElementsByClassName(document, 'table', 'vars'));
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       hideAll(getElementsByClassName(document, 'ol', 'pre-context'));
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       hideAll(getElementsByClassName(document, 'ol', 'post-context'));
06-24 23:51:20.396 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       hideAll(getElementsByClassName(document, 'div', 'pastebin'));
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     }
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     function toggle() {
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         var e = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         if (e) {
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:           e.style.display = e.style.display == 'none' ? 'block': 'none';
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:         }
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       }
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       return false;
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     }
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     function varToggle(link, id) {
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       toggle('v' + id);
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       var s = link.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       var uarr = String.fromCharCode(0x25b6);
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       var darr = String.fromCharCode(0x25bc);
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       s.textContent = s.textContent == uarr ? darr : uarr;
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       return false;
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     }
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     function switchPastebinFriendly(link) {
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       s1 = "Switch to copy-and-paste view";
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       s2 = "Switch back to interactive view";
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       link.textContent = link.textContent.trim() == s1 ? s2: s1;
06-24 23:51:20.397 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       toggle('browserTraceback', 'pastebinTraceback');
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       return false;
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     }
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     //-->
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   </script>
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: </head>
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: <body>
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp: <div id="summary">
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   <h1>TypeError at /students/</h1>
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   <pre class="exception_value">__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: &#39;data&#39;</pre>
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:   <table class="meta">
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     <tr>
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       <th>Request Method:</th>
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:       <td>POST</td>
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     </tr>
06-24 23:51:20.398 10891-12481/com.example.kethan.project D/OkHttp:     <tr>
```

this is attendance/student/views.py file

```
    @csrf_exempt
def student_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        students = Student.objects.all()
        serializer = StudentSerializer(students, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return JsonResponse( status=200)
```

this is traceball from django(server) side

```
    Internal Server Error: /students/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kethan/attendanceapi/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/kethan/attendanceapi/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/kethan/attendanceapi/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/kethan/attendanceapi/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kethan/attendanceapi/attendance/student/views.py", line 21, in student_list
    return JsonResponse( status=200)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
[25/Jun/2017 04:09:25] "POST /students/ HTTP/1.1" 500 72196
```

Comment: try call your api from postman and see it is working. from log it seem to me that it is server error .

Comment: In the question you said that you are doing a get request but in the logs I see that django server received a post request.

Comment: Please post views.py from `attendance/student/views.py`

Comment: Which request does not work? punch or studentList()?

Comment: I don't see the views.py file and also copy the traceback from server logs. It's pretty hard to get the traceback from the error html response

Comment: @ArpitSolanki i have added the view.py and traceball as u asked for it

Comment: May I see your postman request?

Comment: @Meikiem it works fine with post man. i send (name,mobile,time,late) fields and do a post request then it gives all these details and an id.

Comment: How are you sending these items(name, mobile, time, late) in postman? are you sending them in the body?

Comment: @Meikiem yes i have send tgem in the body

Comment: @Kethan Chauhan please test this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution if you are sending your datas in postman  in body request:

make a class like this:

```
public class PunchRequest {
    private String code;
    private String mobile;
    private String time;
    private String late;

    public punch(String code, String mobile, String time, String late) {
        this.code = code;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.time = time;
        this.late = late;
    }
}
```

and change your service in this way:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("students/")
Call<Person> punch( @Body PunchRequest request));
```

and test it, let me know about the result